# How to display Protected Images in Email Messages

Tags: image, laravel, email, html-email, avatar

I am creating a web app using Laravel 5.3 where only authorised users can view the images in that app. For example, lets says something like Facebook where only friends can view the user's avatar if the permission is set like that. When the image is viewed from the app, the api check the `auth` credentials, check the permission and displays the user image accordingly. However, my question is, if I am sending a notification emails to users, how can I display the protected images in email messages? For example, if I add the `img` url like this in html email:

```
<img src="http://example.com/api/image/useravatarname.jpg" />
```

the above will fail since it doesnt have a token in it. In these cases, how are protected emails displayed in emails? How does website like Facebook does it?

These are the methods I have thought of but not happy with:

1) **Embed Image Binary Data:** I don't know if adding the image binary data will work in html emails. Even if it does, it doesn't seem like a good method when sending emails.

2) **Image URL Parameter:** I was thinking maybe to add some parameters like the user's email address `?xyz@gmail.com` to the `img` source url and then from the api locate the user with that email id and verify if they have the permission to view the image. But the problem with it is, some people can view the image by adding the email id parameter easily by guessing.

3) **Facebook Notification Email:** When I checked the facebook notification email, I see the avatars in the email are displayed something like this and I have no idea what they are doing here:

```
https://ci5.googleusercontent.com/proxy/lkjasdlkjsaldjalsjdlasjdlkjasdljsaldjasldlasdljqljaldjsaldjsaldlsajdlsajdlkasjdkljasldkjaslkdjsakldjsaljdlsajdlasjdla#https://scontent-syd2-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p100x100/ljsdlkjsdljsdljsd_23232323_23232_n.jpg?oh=askaslkalsjalsjalksjalkjsas&oe=58C270EEE
```

Is there another way?

Comment: You cannot integrate it into an email service providers like Google, Yahoo, etc..

Comment: updated my question with methods I was thinking atm.